# CSS grid underline (width issues) inside scrolling container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In this example the underlining border for some reason  doesn't span whole width of container, would appreciate any idea how to fix it.

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 3.5fr) minmax(80px, 1fr);
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.grid-underline {

  border-top: 2px solid green;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item">helllo</div>
    <div class="item">world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-underline"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1f9xrsaj/

Comment: Looks working to me. Your `.outer-container` has a `width: 200px` so your underline border's width will be 200px as well.

Comment: But `grid-container`'s width is more, so maybe there are way to make underline border's width match  `grid-container`'s width

Comment: The `.grid-underline` is the child of `.outer-container` and has nothing to do with `.grid-container`. Its width is set to `width: 100%` by you and inherits the width of its parent as 200px. You can either increase the width of `.outer-container` or set the width of `grid-underline` to something bigger than its parent such as `1000px`.

Comment: 1000px seems inaccurate, may be there is js function to get exact width of grid-container content ?

Comment: The grid container width is 200px. It's written in his code which regulates the max width of its child by default unless you want to break it.1000px is only an example. He can change to anything he wants but I doubt he knows how wide he wants because the problem is not the width. It's about he didn't understand the relationship among parents and children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the container a grid one to have all the elements inside the same column and have the same width:

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  display:grid;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 3.5fr) minmax(80px, 1fr);
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.grid-underline {
  border-top: 2px solid green;
}

.item {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item">helllo</div>
    <div class="item">world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-underline"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 3.5fr) minmax(80px, 1fr);
  /*padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;*/
}

/*.grid-underline {

  border-top: 2px solid green;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}*/

.item {
  background: pink padding-box;
  border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 -1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item">helllo</div>
    <div class="item">world</div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="grid-underline"></div> -->
</div>
```